# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar columnas según su valor? (string)

Tags: python

Quiero seleccionar los jugadores que tienen en la columna 'Posición' una 'MC' y un 'EI', solo me funciona con una variable, pero no me deja combinar dos. Uso str.contains.

`FINAL = FINAL[(FINAL["Posición"].str.contains("MC"))]`

Comment: `FINAL[FINAL["Posición"]=="MC"]`

Comment: @Christian. ¿Y el 'El' qué?

Comment: @CandidMoe mejor voy a dar una respuesta

Comment: @CandidMoe Extremo Izquierdo (EI), perdón, quiero combinar los dos, pero no me deja.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder seleccionar columnas segun un valor, se puede usar un *filtro* para solo obtener las columnas con el valor que le indiquemos

```py
FINAL[FINAL["Posición"]=="MC"]
```

Pero como tu quieres seleccionar segun 2valores podemos usar el método `isin()`

```py
FINAL[FINAL["Posición"].isin(["MC","El"])]
```

Esto comprueba si la columna contiene cualquiera de los 2 valores que le haz pasado a `isin()`, esto recibe como parámetro una lista con los valores que quieres comprobar.

Comment: Gracias, pero si hago el de FINAL[FINAL["Posición"].isin(["MC","El"])], solo me elige los que tienen MC como su posición.

Comment: comprueba que el nombre este bien escrito (mayúsculas y minúsculas) y que no tenga espacios